# What is a workspace in a content repository?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository

Starting out with JCR and Jackrabbit I do not understand what a workspace is and how it is intended to be used. And why is it named workspace in the firstplace? Are repositories like databases, workspaces like tables and items like rows (or pretty much)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each JCR workspace is like a different root in your content tree, so you can have a node at /foo in workspace A and a different node /foo in workspace B.

A node can have corresponding nodes in other workspaces: the /foo node of workspace A can be cloned to /foo in workspace B, creating a corresponding node. Both nodes can then live their own life for a while, while being kept corresponding which allows for updating one with the content of the other with one JCR call later.

That could be used for content staging, for example, where one workspace holds the live content of a website while another holds staged content.

I'm not sure what the comparison with a database would be, maybe distinct schemas with some functions that allow for updating one set of tables with another set's data.

In my team (Apache Sling, Adobe CQ/AEM) we always use a single workspace, from my experience multiple workspaces would make things more complicated and less transparent that I like them to be.

http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DavidsModel Rule #3 recommends using workspaces only if you need clone(), merge() and update(), that's good advice in my opinion, and I would seriously check if those methods meet my need before using workspaces.

Comment: Thanks, do you know about books etc that teach how you should organize the nodes in hierarchy and so on. I never used a content repository before and I am not able to find any tutorials.

Comment: I don't think there are any books on that unfortunately, and it's a pity because that's a key element of success with JCR. I wrote an article a while ago ( http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2009/04/cq5tags.html ) that might provide some useful insight, and you could expose your use cases to the Apache Jackrabbit users list ( http://jackrabbit.apache.org/mailing-lists.html ) to get some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Workspaces are working copies of the JCR that you make local updates to before committing the updates to the master copy of the JCR.

Comment: Although you could use them in that way, that's only one way of using them.